# NSFetchedResultsController initWithFetchRequest throws EXE-BAD-ACCESS exception

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, nsfetchedresultscontroller, ios-4.2

I have an `NSFetchedResultsController` inside a subclass of `UITableViewController` inside a `UINavigationController`.  When I run the app, everything works perfectly the first three times I access the view (going to it, then clicking 'Back', then going to it again), but on the fourth (always) it crashes with the following:

`-[NSEntityDescription subentitiesByName]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x8b09c80`

Any help would be much appreciated.

---

Here is my getter for the results controller:

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController*)eventsResultsController {

  if (eventsResultsController_ == nil) {

    NSFetchRequest *aFetchRequest = [[PADataContext sharedInstance] makeGetAllFetchRequestForEntity:@"PAEvent" sortedBy:@"when" ascending:NO];

    // NOTE: crashes on this next line
    NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedResultsContorller = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:aFetchRequest managedObjectContext:[[PADataContext sharedInstance] managedObjectContext] sectionNameKeyPath:@"whenMonth" cacheName:@"AllEvent"];

    self.eventsResultsController = aFetchedResultsContorller;

    [aFetchedResultsContorller release];

  }

  return eventsResultsController_;

}
```

This is the code I use to create my `NSFetchRequest`:

```
- (NSFetchRequest*)makeGetAllFetchRequestForEntity:(NSString*)entityName sortedBy:(NSString*)sortString ascending:(BOOL)ascending {

  NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[[NSFetchRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
  NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:entityName inManagedObjectContext:[self managedObjectContext]];
  [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

  if (sortString != nil) {

    // add sorting information
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:sortString ascending:ascending];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];

    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

    [sortDescriptors release];
    [sortDescriptor release];

  }

  [entity release];
  return fetchRequest;

}
```

The context object is created once and held throughout the lifetime of the app in a singleton.

I have checked the ensure the `eventsResultsController_` gets released when the view controller gets `dealloc`ed.

In the stack, I'm told it crashed in the `initWithFetchRequest:managedObjectContext:sectionNameKeyPath:cacheName` method:

```
#0  0x00f04057 in ___forwarding___
#1  0x00f03f22 in __forwarding_prep_0___
#2  0x00da1b4d in -[NSFetchedResultsController initWithFetchRequest:managedObjectContext:sectionNameKeyPath:cacheName:]
#3  0x00008c94 in -[PAHistoryListTableView eventsResultsController] at PAHistoryListTableView.m:125
#4  0x00008a5b in -[PAHistoryListTableView loadData] at PAHistoryListTableView.m:52
#5  0x00008a2a in -[PAHistoryListTableView viewDidLoad] at PAHistoryListTableView.m:43
...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You created your entity with a non-retaining call:

```
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:entityName inManagedObjectContext:[self managedObjectContext]];
```

And then you released it:

```
[entity release];
```

Take out the release. This is trivial to find when you focus on the fact that it was the `NSEntityDescription` that was over-released. You only use that in one place, so it's easy to find the mistake.

Comment: Wouldn't `NSFetchRequest`'s `setEntity` method retain it?

Comment: Nope. Apple's memory management rules are here: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmObjectOwnership.html

Comment: That's not your business. That's NSFetchRequest's business. If NSFetchRequest retains it, then it's NSFetchRequest's responsibility to release it. You only release things you retained (by calling `alloc`, `retain` or `new`).

Comment: I see, and since I didn't `alloc` the `NSEntityDescription`, I shouldn't worry about it.  Thanks again.