# Message sent to deallocated instance Core Data

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I am getting the title error when trying to add a string to Core Data. Here is my code:

```
 func save(name: String) {
        let model = CoreDataModel(modelName: modelName, modelBundle: modelBundle!, storeType: .SQLite(DocumentsDirectoryURL()))
        let factory = CoreDataFactory(model: model)

        let context = factory.createContext()
        let entity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Transaction", inManagedObjectContext: context)
        let transaction = NSManagedObject(entity: entity!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: context)

        transaction.setValue(name, forKey: "name")

        do {
            try context.save()
            transactions.append(transaction)
        }catch let error as NSError {
            print(error)
        }
    }


func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
   let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell")

   let transaction = transactions[indexPath.row]
   print(transaction)
   cell!.textLabel!.text = transaction.valueForKey("name") as? String 

   return cell!
}
```

The error is on this line:

```
cell!.textLabel!.text = transaction.valueForKey("name") as? String
```

And this is the complete error description:

```
<NSManagedObject: 0x7f9d5c216a90> (entity: <null>; id: 0xd000000000040000 <x-coredata://442A125F-AB41-4CA3-AAA5-A5C59840D5EE/Transaction/p1> ; data: <fault>)
2016-04-13 19:25:29.207 Project1[22981:2242560] *** -[NSEntityDescription _entityClass]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x7f9d5c2089e0
```

Anyone has an idea why I am getting this ?

Comment: you should probably populate you transactions array from the fetch from data store, after each update, instead of appending just created managed object to it.

Comment: will do that later, but now trying to fix this issue, when adding the first item.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the problem was that I created the `NSManagedObjectContext` locally to save(), I had to move the first 3 lines to `ViewDidLoad`, and declare `context` as a class member.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4899356/nsfetchedresultscontroller-initwithfetchrequest-throws-exe-bad-access-exception) thread helped me figure it out.

Comment: that's kind of what I meant :))